# Create Delete and Rename in jstree not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jstree

I am working with jstree for the first time.I am trying with create, rename and deletion operation with jstree. I am creating the tree with json data by fetching from database in codeigniter. Here I have given a function in controller. Buttons for creation renaming and deletion are in view page. And functions are in controller. This code forming three trees dynamically. But those buttons are working on the last tree only. Other two trees id is getting null for those operations. I am unable to know where is the mistake is.

Can anyone help me with this. If my question is not clear please ask me.

Here is the code

```
public function accounts()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $accountids = $this->Accounts_model->getaccounts();
    $i=1;
    $function='';
    foreach($accountids as $accountid){
        $htmll='';
        $html='';
        $json='[';
        $jstree='';
        $jstree.='$("#'.preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $accountid['accname']).'")';
        $function.='function demo_create() {
                    var ref = $("#'.preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $accountid['accname']).'").jstree(true),
                        sel = ref.get_selected();
                        console.log(sel);
                        alert(sel);
                    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
                    sel = sel[0];
                    sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});
                    if(sel) {
                        ref.edit(sel);
                    }
                };
                function demo_rename() {
                    var ref = $("#'.preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $accountid['accname']).'").jstree(true),
                        sel = ref.get_selected();
                        console.log(sel);
                        alert(sel);
                    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
                    sel = sel[0];
                    ref.edit(sel);
                };
                function demo_delete() {
                    var ref = $("#'.preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $accountid['accname']).'").jstree(true),
                        sel = ref.get_selected();
                        console.log(sel);
                        alert(sel);
                    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
                    ref.delete_node(sel);
                };';
                $html.='<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td><div id="'.preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $accountid['accname']).'">"'.$accountid['accname'].'"';
                $json.='{"id":"'.$accountid['accname'].'","parent":"#","text":"'.$accountid['accname'].'","type":"account"},';

                $sub_accountids= $this->Accounts_model->get_subaccounts($accountid['id']);

                foreach($sub_accountids as $sub_accid){
                    $json.='{"id":"'.$sub_accid['subAccname'].'","parent":"'.$accountid['accname'].'","text":"'.$sub_accid['subAccname'].'","type":"tranche"},';
                }       
                $htmll.='</div></td><td><div class="account_ox" id="'.$accountid['id'].'"><a href="#"><img src="'.JS_FOLDER_PATH.'/image/add.png" data-toggle="modal" width="27px" height="27px" class="cat" data-target="#myModal2" onclick="testleena('.$regionid['id'].');"/></a><input type="hidden" id="hiding" value="'.$accountid['id'].'"/></div></td></tr>';
                $i++;
                $json=rtrim($json,",");
                $json.=']';     

                echo $html.'<script>'.$function.'$(document).ready(function() {'.$jstree.'.jstree({  
                    "core" : {
                    "data" : 
                        '.$json.',
                        "check_callback":true
                    }
                });
                $(".account_ox").click(function (){
                        $("#opex_hiddenid").val(this.id);
                });
                });</script>'.$htmll;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, show a fully rendered page with jstree and data (maybe using https://jsfiddle.net/ ), otherwise it is virtually impossible to imagine what is wrong with your view.

Comment: Hi Vaviloff. Thank you for your reply. I did that successfully. now create , rename and delete function is working properly. 

But the node its creating is having id in jx_y format. and I am not able to catch the name. Is there any way to catch the proper id and name of the newly created node. or renamed node.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question in the latest comment. As I said, please show the HTML page generated with PHP together with a sample of JSON data, then I may be able to help you.

Comment: [{"id":"Pay","parent":"#","text":"Pay","type":"account"},{"id":"1","parent":"Pay","text":"Salaries ","type":"subaccount"},{"id":"2","parent":"Pay","text":"Bonus ","type":"subaccount"},{"id":"3","parent":"Pay","text":"Commissions","type":"subaccount"}]

Comment: This is the data for one tree. in json format . I am fetching it from database.

Comment: for creation of node I am having a function.
function demo_create() {
       
       var ref = $("#"+GlobalVariable).jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();
        alert(sel);
        console.log(sel);
        
       if(!sel.length) { return false; }
       sel = sel[0];
       sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});
       if(sel) {
        ref.edit(sel);
       }
      };

Comment: But after creation of new node I need that id and name of the node to store in database. But I am not getting how to fetch the name.

Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `get_node` to get the name of the new node based on the new node id you have in your `sel` variable.
Like this: `$("#"+treeId).jstree().get_node(sel).text`

Check out demo - select a node to add child, then click button Create Node: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/hxg1brgk/)

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay .. :)

Comment: You are welcome! Did it help given that you asked your question 4 months ago? ))